# Are time-lapse questions off topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked a [question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61528/how-to-do-1-hz-timelapse-photography-with-canon-7d) about time-lapse photography, and was effectively told within minutes that it would be a better fit for [VP.SE](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/15220/how-to-do-1-hz-timelapse-photography-with-canon-7d) (including an unexplained down-vote). Is it really off topic for this site? I mean, the only "video production" I do with the resulting images is [call `ffmpeg`](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/276211a3be790b96a9d8507f812c23869de16282/.bash_history#L217), which is completely unrelated to the issue in the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Time-lapse photography is not necessarily off topic for the site. Even if a question (not necessarily the one you asked) might be a better fit for Videography it can still be on topic here if the answers have merit in still photography.

As an aside, down votes are not normally explained here. It's entirely up to the user to do so, we don't generally push for it.